# Angular-js - ng-repeat doesn't work if the first element is null

Tags: angularjs, null, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects and sometimes some of them are null

```
<div ng-repeat="submission in data.Submissions">
    <div ng-if="submission">
        {{submission.SubmissionId}}
    </div>
</div>
```

if the first object in the array is null, nothing renders at all.  If the first element is not null, it renders no problem.

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ng-repeat="submission in data.Submissions track by $index">
    <div ng-if="submission">
        {{submission.SubmissionId}}
    </div>
</div>
```